# Screenshot is not showing for failed testcase in Jenkins report

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

Failed tets case screenshot is showing as a broken image in the Jenkis report.  I am using TestNG for reporting. When i tried to open image in new tab then following ulr opened with empty screen- https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuS38.png
How can i handel this Please see screenshot for more details.[Screenshot of broken image with firebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuS38.png)

Answer (score 0):

Archiving should be the solution for your issue!

You archive the screenshot using the "archive the artifacts" option in the "post build actions" of the jenkins project configuration page.To archive first u need to set the custom workspace for the project.The custom workspace should point to the root directory or the folder which is containing the folder of screenshots.Then after archiving all the screenshots will appear as links in the project page.Here "reports" will be folders containing the screenshots or any file.reports is under The "QTP" folder which is mentioned in the custom workspace.pls use slash instead of backslash in the archive the artifacts option.

[image: Screen shot]

Let me know if it worked